# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, python-unicode

I am using python = 3.6
Can't able to get solution for this ?
Can anyone help me to get a solution for this issue!

Comment: Please see [question guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please share a code sample.

Comment: It means that the string you are trying to decode is not encoded using ascii. Try using different decoding format e.g. utf-8 or ask for the original encoding that was used,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `b'\xef or some string here'.decode("utf-8", "ignore")` to simply ignore such an error. Another way of doing it is to use a `try-catch` block.

And either way, you'd probably need to examine [Python Docs on Unicode](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html).

Comment: Thanks for giving this solution!